# Append Items to Databound ItemsControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I've got a Combo Box that is databound to an ObservableCollection of items.  I would like to have a default selected item that is (None) that would set the value of the property I've bound to "SelectedValue" to null.

I think there ought to be a way to achieve this with some combination of Style/DataTemplate/TemplateSelector.  I'm trying to design this with MVVM in mind, so I'd like something that doesn't use codebehind and is as reusable as possible.  I'd also like the benefits of the ObservableCollection (updating the collection causing the control to rebind) to remain intact.

Bonus part B:
I would like to also be able to append an extra visual element to the bottom of an ItemsControl as well.  I was thinking it would be easy to change the DataTemplate if I knew how to trigger it on the last item of a collection.  Willing to entertain other options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I've found to do this is to insert a "special" value into the underlying collection, and display the "(None)" text when it's selected. Obviously then you need to run your binding through a converter to take this value into account and return null when it's selected. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518579/why-cant-i-select-a-null-value-in-a-combobox) of mine which was a result of me trying to add an actual null value to a ComboBox's underlying collection.)

Having said that, it might actually be possible to do what you want with the [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) class. You could make a separate collection (with only one item - your Null item) and bind your ComboBox to both it and your original collection through the CompositeCollection.

Comment: I've tried this.  I'm not getting much luck binding a CollectionContainer's "Collection" property to a property from the object in DataContext (ex. <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TheItems}" />).  Works great from a static resource though... am I missing something here?