# Adding a ListViewItem to an already data-bound ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I'm currently working on making a point of sale and I got it to show items in a ListView that are in the current sale. I did this by DataBinding an ObservableCollection of "Item"-type objects in a static "Sale" class called CurrentSale. Not bad, eh? But I need to add coupons and discounts to my pos now, and it's proving to be difficult with the way WPF is set up.

This:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1330689/listnow.jpg
is how the listview currently looks. This:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1330689/listgoal.jpg
is my mockup of how I'd like a discount to show up. I think I've got the discount and coupon part of the program under control, I'd just like to make them show up. I'd be super thrilled if someone could show me some sample code demonstrating how to insert a custom listviewitem into a listview that's already bound with data, and with similar characteristics(multiple cells, black background)

I read through this:
[Append Items to Databound ItemsControl in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135675/append-items-to-databound-itemscontrol-in-wpf)
and it looks like that guy's got a similar problem. The solutions given to him were to add a special item to the bound list, or to use a CompositeCollection. I can't add a "special" item to the observablecollection, because it doesn't let me change the background color, and I wanted a cleaner solution. Also, I couldn't really find any documentation on CompositeCollections with ListViews, so maybe somebody can shed more light on it(if it's relevant to my problem)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `ListBox` instead of `ListView` and [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

Create base abstract class and 2 subclasses, for instance: `BaseListItem`, `ProductListItem` and `DiscountListItem`. Then insert specific object in the specific place into `ObservableCollection<BaseListItem>` used as `ItemsSource` for your `ListBox`.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful idea! I didn't know DataTemplateSelectors existed before now. Now I just have to get it to work :p but that should happen in no time. Thanks! :)