# Selecting null item in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` with an `ItemsSource` that can contain `null` values.
I can't select those `null` values in the `ListBox` with the mouse, but I can with the keyboard.
Is there any way to make `null` items selectable by mouse?

Example xaml:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <x:Null />
        <system:String>Hello</system:String>
        <x:Null />
    </ListBox.Items>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Null value!" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Which results in:
[image: image of example]
however, I can't select any of the `Null value!` entries using the mouse, which is what I want to do.

If it can be done with another pure-xaml solution, that'd be fine. I'd prefer to not have to use any converters, if possible.

Comment: Null ist not an object. While you can add Null to a collection Null cannot be rendered. You should explicitly insert placeholders (or whatever Null does represent in your logic). An empty string seems to be more reasonable in your context.

Comment: Thing is, I can render the `null` with the style's triggers. This is a simplified example of the issue I run into, and my actual datatype can't really have a placeholder very easily.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid you will have to go for converters (don't really know why you don't want some ?)

[From this SO question :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518579/why-cant-i-select-a-null-value-in-a-combobox)

> The null "item" is not being selected by the keyboard at all - rather
> the previous item is being unselected and no subsequent item is (able
> to be) selected.
>
> In short, you can neither select nor deselect a null item in a
> ComboBox. When you think you are doing so, you are rather deselecting
> or selecting the previous or a new item.
>
> This can perhaps best be seen by adding a background to the items in
> the ComboBox. You will notice the colored background in the ComboBox
> when you select "Hello", but when you deselect it via the keyboard,
> the background color disappears. We know this is not the null item,
> because the null item actually has the background color when we drop
> the list down via the mouse!
>
> The following XAML, modified from that in the original question, will
> put a LightBlue background behind the items so you can see this
> behavior.
>
> ````
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
>     <StackPanel>
>         <ComboBox x:Name="bars" Height="21" SelectedItem="{Binding Bar}">
>             <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate>
>                     <Grid Background="LightBlue" Width="200" Height="20">
>                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
>                     </Grid>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>             </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
>         </ComboBox>
>     </StackPanel> </Window> ```
> ````

> If you want further validation, you can handle the SelectionChanged event on the ComboBox and see that
> "selecting the null item" actually gives an empty array of AddedItems
> in its SelectionChangedEventArgs, and "deselecting the null item by
> selecting 'Hello' with the mouse" gives an empty array of
> RemovedItems.

Comment: Not really relevant, the `null` item can be selected in the `ListBox` using the keyboard. As to why I would prefer not using a converter is simple: reduce converter class spam.

Comment: 1) your answer details nothing, just that converters should be used (how). 2) To me it seems that having specialized converters (in this case, to handle some nulls) is a bad practise, and you should try and keep only to reusable generic converts. 3) I did not downvote your answer, someone did that before I read it. Out of own experiments I found that `SelectedItem` could be bound, and would set it to `null` when using a keyboard, which contradicts what you quoted.

Comment: 1) You are wrong. The answer said that I'm *afraid* there is no other solution, despite the weird behaviour of the framework suggests the opposite. 2) I have no problem with that. But keep in mind that is a 
personal conviction, not an absolute rule. Just make sure it doesn't cause you more problems than it solves. 3) I reproduce what is in the answer (LightBlue background and `SelectionChangedEventArgs`) on my pc. Maybe this behaviour is configuration-based ? If that's the case, personnaly  
I'd run away from this kind of problem, since configure each customer dependencies would be a pain.